# How to pass token in Arm Template while creating API connection in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I am writing azure logic app to trigger release in vsts but not able to find the value to be passed in the token parameter in the attached ARM template image

[image: Arm template metadata]

I have passed like below

> "token": "Personal access token generated from vsts"

Able to establish the connection but not able to trigger the release, getting an error key

> 'Token' in connection profile is not valid unexpected character encounter while parsing value

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid here you need use `Oauth` type instead of `PAT` while you are trying to apply with application.

```
"token": {
            "type": "oauthSetting",
            "oAuthSettings": {
              "identityProvider": "visualstudio",
              "clientId": "xxxxxxxx",
              "scopes": [
                "vso.agentpools_manage vso.build_execute vso.chat_manage vso.code_manage vso.code_status vso.connected_server vso.dashboards_manage vso.entitlements vso.extension.data_write vso.extension_manage vso.identity vso.loadtest_write vso.packaging_manage vso.project_manage vso.release_manage vso.test_write vso.work_write"
              ],
              "redirectUrl": "xxxxxxx",
              "properties": {
                "IsFirstParty": "False"
              }
            },
            "uiDefinition": {
              "displayName": "Login with Visual Studio Team Services Credentials",
              "description": "Login with Visual Studio Team Services Credentials",
              "tooltip": "Provide Visual Studio Team Services Credentials",
              "constraints": {
                "required": "true"
              }
            }
          }
```

In this body format, only `clientId`, `scopes` and `redirectUrl` you should pay attention to based on your actual app.

`clientId`: This is the id that assigned to your logic app after registered [here](https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/app/register).

`scopes`: The scopes that you assigned to logic app, so that the app has enough permission to finish corresponding operation. This depend on your app logic. See this list: [Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#scopes). **Note:** Space separated while you are specifying multi scopes here.

`redirectUrl`: The callback URL for your app. Note: It must exactly match the URL registered with the app.

Comment: Can we send like this when creating a connection 

"token": {         
              "clientId": "xxxxxxxx",
              "scopes": [
                "vso.agentpools_manage vso.build_execute vso.chat_manage vso.code_manage vso.code_status vso.connected_server vso.dashboards_manage vso.entitlements vso.extension.data_write vso.extension_manage vso.identity vso.loadtest_write vso.packaging_manage vso.project_manage vso.release_manage vso.test_write vso.work_write"
              ],
              "redirectUrl": "xxxxxxx"
            }

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy, No, identity provider can not be ignore. That used for VSTS.

Comment: Do i need to pass like this 
"token": {            
            "oAuthSettings": { "identityProvider": "visualstudio",  "clientId": "xxxxxxxx",  
   "scopes": [
              ],
              "redirectUrl": "xxxxxxx"            
   }
  }

Comment: Or Shall I use like this  "token": {            
              "identityProvider": "visualstudio",
              "clientId": "xxxxxxxx",
              "scopes": [
              ],
              "redirectUrl": "xxxxxxx"            
  }

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy, the previous one is available.

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy, Could you show me how's your script like? 401 normally represent token format is ok, but not available for operation.

Comment: I am sending exactly like this 
"token": { "oAuthSettings": { "identityProvider": "visualstudio", "clientId": "xxxxxxxx", "scopes": [all the scopes given], "redirectUrl": "https://logic-apis-brazilsouth.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect" } }

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy Did you use fiddler to monitor this progress? It can show more details, stack trace would much be better.

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy Hi, were you able to fix the issue?